# How to stop my do while loop from accepting every single string except "stop"

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, integer

> Write a main method that asks the user for an integer `n` which then allocates an array of ints of that size and stores that many integers as the user enters them. Once they are all entered, print them in the reverse order of how they were entered.

This is what I have come up, thus far (any help will be greatly appreciated):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Array2D {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> number = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int ber = 0;
        String stop = "";

        System.out.println("Type as many number as you like, to get in reverse order. When done typing number, type STOP: ");
        do{
            try{
                ber = num.nextInt();
                number.add(ber);
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException e){
                stop = num.nextLine();
                e.equals(stop);
            }




        }while(!(stop.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")));
```

Comment: Also, as the title implies, I want the program to only receive "stop", to jump out of the loop. Again any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What doesn't work? What's the problem?

Comment: `List` != `array`. Your code is not solution for task from your question.

Comment: It works, but it's not doing what I want it to do. It's accepting every string I (the user) types. And I just want the string "stop" to be accepted, so it can drop out of the loop.

Comment: Pshemo, You are right. Thanks for the distinction. Do you have an idea on how to use an array instead? I tried using an array, and can't seem to create an infinite array for the user to put as many integer the user would like. And that's why I switched to, an ArrayList, I thought it was an array as well.

Comment: "*and can't seem to create an infinite array*" and why would you want to create infinite array? In your question it is clear that you should first ask user for `n` which then you can use to create array with proper size `new int[n]` and fill with next `n` elements from user. About: "*I switched to, an ArrayList, I thought it was an array as well.*" `ArrayList` is not array, but it is list which stores its elements in its internal array. In case array will be too small it creates new one 2x bigger and copies old elements to new array which will be used instead of old one.

Comment: Have written an answer that will only accept "Stop" to stop. Did that help you?

Comment: It did accept stop and terminated the program; however, it kept accepting every other string I typed without terminating. Thank you anyway, and it also helped to see how a for loop is used to get the reverse of an array.

Comment: I got it to work. Thank you everyone. Here is what I came up with, with your help (I'll post it below to maintain formatting):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Task from your question is asking you to do something like this (there is no even need to handle case where user writes `stop` or other incorrect data, but you can handle them if you want).

```
//ask user for array size
int n = getInt();
//create array for n integers
int[] array = new int[n];
//read n integers from user
for (i in 0..n-1)
    tmp = readInt()
    //and store them in array
    put tmp in array at position i

//print content of array backwards
for (i in n-1..0)
    print(i-th element from array)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the catch to :

```
catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    if(stop.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")){
       continue;
    }
    stop = num.nextLine();
    e.equals(stop);
}
```

And for printing them in reverse order:

```
for (int i= (number.size()-1); i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.println(number.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int n = 0;
Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to display: ");
n = num.nextInt();
int[] number = new int[n];

System.out.println("Enter the numbers: ");

for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
    number[i] = num.nextInt();      
}

System.out.println("Here they are in reverse! ");

for(int i = n-1; i >= 0; --i){
    System.out.println(number[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need arraylist for the problem statement. Just the basic code logic using arrays.

```
void print reverse(int n){
    int[] arr = new int[n];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; --i){
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

print them in the reverse order

```
for (int i = number.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.println(number.get(i));
}
```